# Как повторить чтение если ввели не число

Tags: c++

Мне нужно написать небольшую программу для подсчёта объёма и площади поверхности куба по ребру. Но нужно учесть, что если пользователь вводит не цифру, то прога должна давать ещё попытку... Пожалуйста, напишите как это сделать без ошибок

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, V, S;
    setlocale(0, "");
    {
        cout << "Введите длину ребра куба: ";
        cin >> a;
    } 

    V = a * a * a;
    S = (a * a) * 6;

    cout << "\nV=" << V;
    cout << "\nS=" << S << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    while(1)
    {
        if (isNumber(a)) break;
        else cin >> a;
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем у вас проверка после вычислений?

Comment: Да, пожалуй вы правы. Даже если я переставлю, он напишет... [Error] 'isNumber' was not declared in this scope

Comment: например [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/)

Comment: вместо isNumber

Comment: Спасибо, Grundy!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

После попытки ввода числа, проверяйте результат функции `fail()`. Если ввод был не удачным, очищайте флаг неудачи с помощью `clear()`, пропускайте символы до конца строки, и читайте число еще раз.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    int x;
    while ((std::cin >> x).fail()) {
        if (std::cin.eof() || std::cin.bad())
            return 1;  // Входной поток закончился или помер, дальше читать смысла нет.
        std::cout << "error, try again\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    std::cout << "V=" << x*x*x;
}
```